# Combining two led strips with separate controllers

Tags: led

Out of practice and have forgotten basic principles but would like to combine two led strips to one controller so they operate in sync. Have combined output from sensor into control box but outputs from control boxes not in sync when using RGB light shows. How can I split output from one controller to two light strips using driver and controller in image. Thanks[image]

Comment: nothing to do with practice – we have no idea how that light strip likes to be controlled, so hard to tell. Chances are it's WS82xx compatible, but that's just guessing at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by *output of controller not in sync*? Is it the brightness, color, speed of animation ? Provide some more information about the parameters that are not in sync.

Comment: @MarcusMüller from the picture, it looks like the controller actually outputs RGBW directly, so not addressable LEDs, just plain LEDs all showing the same colour at the same time I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If the controller output parameters like brightness, speed of animation, color are not in sync between the two led strips then you need to reset both controllers to there initial states.

These kind of controllers store the previously set parameters in their memory and thus are able to start from the previously know state on each power cycle. You must have set different parameters for the two controllers before you combined the receiver sensor output. 

i.e. If brightness in one was set to 50 and in the other to 25, then since they have common receiver sensor now, on increasing brightness by 10, one will increase to 60 and the other to 35.

To fix this sync problem you need to just keep lowering the brightness / speed of animation / the parameter not in sync, until the parameters become equal on both.

Comment: They may never be in sync, though. Since the controllers have unsynchronized clocks, there will inevitably be drift in the animation.